# SVN configuration problem

Tags: svn

Configured the SVN with `httpd` service including below modules but it gives an error as below:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

error:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 206 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: 
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: undefined symbol: 
svn_mergeinfo__remove_prefix_from_catalog
```

Server version:

```
Apache/2.2.3 Server built: Nov 12 2008 07:09:27 RHEL 5.4 - 32 bit
```

How would you troubleshoot this error message?

Comment: change your apache version to 2.0

Answer (score 3):

This is usually associated with older versions of the libsvn present on your server: see [this thread](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2009-02/0403.shtml).

> Could it be that you still have an older version of the Subversion libraries somewhere?
>   If so, remove them. `mod_dav_svn` may be trying to link with the wrong version.
>
> This is assuming that you did update `/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so` with the new one.
>   Otherwise, it could be that `mod_dav_svn` is the old part and it's having trouble linking with the newer Subversion libraries.

You find the same upgrade advice in [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=488996http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=488996).